# start laravel project inside electron project

Tags: php, laravel, electron

i created a laravel project inside electron js  the issue is that first I have to use `php artisan serve` commad inside the laravel project then only when I start my electron  with `npm start` the laravel project will work  how can i over come this issue

what i want is when i start the electron project  with `npm start` the  `php artisan serve` must also work with it

here is a diretory list of my app
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)?

Comment: "must also work with it" - what does that mean? Do you have any specific question about your requirement?

Comment: @AdarshMohan what i am trying to do is make a desktop app using laravel and electron  https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-desktop-application-using-electron-js

Comment: @NicoHaase  when i do npm start only my electron app is geting started it does not start my laraval

Comment: @NicoHaase my question is simple i have a electron js project and a laravel project i just want to put the laravel project inside electronjs proejct so that my larvel project will turn into a desktop app the issue i am facing is that there are 2 seprate commads to start both electron and laraval , what i want is when the commad to  electron is enterd the laravel proejct also must start

Comment: @NicoHaase what are u not understanding in this questtion it is quite clear for me

Comment: looks like you are running the command from the root folder and artisan is in the www folder

Comment: the laravel project is inside of www and i am running command from route  thats true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the documentation your provided here : [Laravel desktop application using Electron Js](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-desktop-application-using-electron-js)

and everything seems to work pretty well, however you need to know:
**You don't need to use `php artisan serve` npm will do all the work for you.**

**Everything must be in one directory**,

- start by creating a new directory for example: stack
- inside the stack follow step 1,2 from the documentation you provided.
- make sure to install php-server :

  npm i --save node-php-server
- in the step 3 (**"Making directories"**) inside stack create two directories as follow:
  stack/php : here copy your php folder that contains the bin/php.exe ....etc
  stack/www : here create your laravel project (Note: make it here, not a sub directory, so it's like stack/www/public , stack/www/artisan ....etc).
- if you want to edit the directories as you want, pay attention to the following lines in step 4 from the link above:

as a note:

```
phpServer.createServer({
        port: port,
        hostname: host,
        base: `${__dirname}/www/public`,
        keepalive: false,
        open: false,
        bin: `${__dirname}/php/php.exe`,
        router: __dirname + '/www/server.php'
});
```

- base: is the laravel public folder
- bin : is the bin file to PHP CLI
- router: is the server.php file from laravel project

Comment: @Al.Aissat i  have allredy followed these steps when i do npm start i get white screen with `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: i have added the error in question as a scrren shot

Comment: @jisaks i don't see server.php in your laravel folder , and implementation won't work with artisan but with server.php provided from laravel ... **You need to have server.php in www**

Comment: ok can u pls tell me what code must come inside server.php to work

Comment: @jisaks this link what you need: [github](https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-laravel/blob/main/server.php)

Comment: oke @Ak.Aissat now my larval project aso is starting along wih electron but i have one more issue  i have do extra `npm run dev`  inside www folder to start vite then only my css is loading is there any method inoder to start that also with npm start

Comment: @jisaks you need to know that **Its sole purpose is to serve assets, such as scripts or stylesheets. It is not where your application is served** so you need to run it obviously, if you want to stop using npm run dev for vite you need to **do build for production using npm** , that's depending the research I made, I'm not that familiar with vite.. hope i helped.